# What does the phrase "He held that a man who can observe is a man apart" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

> I knew this game. **Lundist held that a man who can observe is a man apart**. Such a man can see opportunities where others see only the obstacles on the surface of each situation.

This is a quotation from Prince of Thorns, chapter 11.
How does this sentence work?
Is "*he held that a man*" equal to "*he is a man*"?
I've googled that "*a man apart*" = "*standing apart because he has different traits*" but I can't make any sense of the sentence. Why is there "***is*** a man apart"? What kind of grammar is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Held is the past participle of "hold." "Hold" here means "to believe or have a particular opinion about something." Here, it has been used with a clause following it. "a man who can observe" is the subject of the sentence "a man who can observe is a man apart." I speculate "a man apart" is also the reduced form of "a man who is apart."

Comment: I take "a man apart" to mean "a man who is special". I suppose by "a man who can observe" he means someone like Sherlock Holmes, someone who is able to make very careful observations, which is not a skill everyone has.

Comment: @Ilya  For more on the meaning of *a man apart*, see: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30331/what-does-a-man-apart-mean